# data retrieving from a view to UITableViewCell in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting the same error in Xcode and couldnt figure out why (my bad)
I'm trying to retrieve the data that's been saved using uitexfield code below
that part is for saving

```
- (IBAction)saveCourseDetail:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableDictionary *courseDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    [courseDictionary setObject:courseName.text forKey:@"courseName"];
    [courseDictionary setObject:courseDescription.text forKey:@"courseDescription"];
    [courseDictionary setObject:classRoom.text forKey:@"classRoom"];
    [courseDictionary setObject:teacherName.text forKey:@"teacherName"];
    [courseDictionary setObject:buildingName.text forKey:@"buildingName"];

    NSUserDefaults *savedData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [savedData setObject:courseDictionary forKey:@"courseDictionary"];
    [savedData synchronize];
//    [self.delegate reloadTableData];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CourseAddedNotification" object:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
#pragma  mark Course Tableview


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *string = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell==nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=string;

        return cell;
    }
    and the tableview that i'm trying to get the saved course details 



#pragma  mark - Table View Delegate -

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CourseCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CourseCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

but I keep getting the same error which- 
2013-11-26 14:43:19.496 SidebarDemo[1170:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:5261
2013-11-26 14:43:19.500 SidebarDemo[1170:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have a prototype cell in your storyboard with an Identifer of Cell?

Answer (score 0):

you must set the cell identifier in storyboard in the attributinspector the 4.tab. the identifier must be equal to the identifier in your source code(here "Cell").

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"messageCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Do not use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Apple Documentation:

Important

You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or    registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

Add `identifier` to your `uitableviewCell` in `storyboard`, give name "Cell" same as you are using in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method